# Is the unit ball of a dense set dense?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed vector space, and let $Y \subset X$ be a dense subset of $X$. Does it follow that $\{y: y \in Y, ||y|| \leq 1\}$ is dense in $\{x: x \in X, ||x|| \leq 1\}$?

Comment: It would seem like “Yes” to me if the balls were open, because in a proof by contradiction, if you assume that for some $x$ there was an open set that contained it that was disjoint from that subset of $Y$, then you could show there was an open ball of positive radius around it that did not intersect $Y$. However, I’m not sure if some interesting counterexample exists for the closed ball.

Comment: If your spaces are real or complex, it does follow. I'm not sure if there are exotic scalar fields over which it may fail.

Comment: Please clarify if $X$ is a real or complex space.

Comment: @user251257 $X$ is real!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ stand for the unit ball. Then the answer is yes if $closure(interior(B)) = B$.

Let $x \in B$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. We have to show that there is a $y \in Y \cap B$ within $\varepsilon$ of $x$.

Since $Y$ is dense in $X$, there is a $z \in Y$ with $\delta$ of $x$ for any $\delta > 0$.
Thus, if $x \in interior(B)$, then we can pick $\delta = \min \{{1-||x||,\varepsilon\}}$ small enough so that $z \in B$, and hence $z \in B \cap Y$.

If $x$ has $||x|| = 1$, then we will reduce it to the first case as follows: Pick another point $x' \in interior(B)$ within $\varepsilon /2$ of $x$, which exists because $closure(interior(B)) = B$. Now since $x'$ is in the interior, we can use the first case to find a point $z' \in B \cap Y$ within $\varepsilon /2$ of $x'$. By triangle inequality, this is within $\varepsilon$ of $x$.

Note that we did not need to use fully that $Y$ was dense in $X$, just that its dense in $B$.

Comment: Why does $x'$ exist?

Comment: $B$ being a convex closed set, we do have $B = \overline{B^\circ}$ as you need. This is a standard fact for normed spaces.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Do you have a reference for this fact? If so it would help me greatly.

Comment: I know it as a standard fact, no reference off the top of my head.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: For every field of scalars?

Comment: @JCAA reals or complex.

Comment: The question does nor specify the field of scalars. It can be a field for which your statement is false.

Comment: @JCAA Unless otherwise specified normed spaces are over the scalars $\Bbb R$. That's often not even mentioned.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article "normed vector spaces" the field is allowed to be rational numbers and the norm $p$-adic. It is quite possibble that the OP meant real or complex but strictly speaking that should be mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Let $x \in X$ such that $\lVert x \rVert \le 1$. Consider $\epsilon > 0$.

Define $x_n = \frac{n-1}{n}x$. Then $\lVert x_n \rVert = \frac{n-1}{n}\lVert x \rVert < 1$ and $\lVert x - x_n \rVert < \epsilon/2$ for $n \ge N$. Since $Y$ is dense, there exists $y_N \in Y$ such that $\lVert y_N - x_N \rVert < \min(\epsilon/2, 1 - \lVert x_N \rVert$. Then $\lVert x - y_N \rVert \le  \lVert x - x_N \rVert + \lVert x_N - y_N \rVert < \epsilon$ and $\lVert y_N \rVert \le \lVert y_N - x_N \rVert + \lVert x_N \rVert < 1 - \lVert x_N \rVert + \lVert x_N \rVert = 1$.

Comment: @user251257 Usually a normed vector space is understood as a vector space over the real or complex numbers. ln my opinion  the OP should have mentioned if he has a different interpretation.

Comment: op has clarified that the space is real. So that is fine. I would silently accept that Banach space is real or complex.